# Change list of variables according to another list containing the index and atoms in prolog

Tags: list, indexing, prolog

I have a list of variables `E` and a list `L` and I want a predicate that works like this:

```
E=[A,B,C,D]
L=[(1,b),(3,m)]
solve(E,L).
E=[b,B,m,D]
```

Basically `solve()` should run through the list `L` and change `E` by using `(a,b)` to unify the variable at index `a` with the atom `B`. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of the (badly named) `solve/2` predicate is something like "for every pair (`Index`, `Element`), the `Index`-th element of the input list is `Element`". You are likely using a Prolog implementation that already has a predicate called something like `nth1/3` which expresses "the `Index`-th element of `List` is `Element`". For example, in SWI-Prolog:

```
?- List = [A, B, C, D], nth1(3, List, this_is_the_third_element).
List = [A, B, this_is_the_third_element, D],
C = this_is_the_third_element.
```

So an alternative implementation of your predicate simply calls `nth1/3` for each of your (`Index`, `Element`) pairs:

```
solve(_List, []).
solve(List, [(Index, Elem) | Pairs]) :-
    nth1(Index, List, Elem),
    solve(List, Pairs).
```

And with this you're done:

```
?- E = [A, B, C, D], L = [(1, b), (3, m)], solve(E, L).
E = [b, B, m, D],
A = b,
C = m,
L = [(1, b),  (3, m)] ;
false.
```

Note that this solution is simple, but it has quadratic complexity in the length of the input list: `nth1/3` might have to visit the entire N-element list N times. In the unlikely case that you need this predicate for a performance-critical part of some larger program, consider the more optimized solution sketched in the other answer.

Comment: That's straightforward. I didn't even think of this.

Answer (score 2):

*Is there any way to do this?*

Certainly. And as they say in Perl: "There is more than one way to do it".

Couple of problems:

Do not use `(1,b)`. Use the idiomatic `-(1,b)` instead, which is written as `1-b` (the pair). This gives you a list of pairs: `L=[1-b,3-m]`. There is a library specifically dealing with such pairs: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs - alternatively you can use real maps implemented with AVL trees: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=assoc

Now you just need to:

1. sort the list of pairs, probably using keysort: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/2 or https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/4
2. Go through the list left to right, keeping the current index, and performing a replacement when the next key in your sorted list is hit, or just retaining the existing term from the list otherwise. The result goes into an accumulator variable as head of a list.
3. Done! Special handling of out-of-bounds indexes etc. to be suitably handled by throwing or failing.

How to go through the sorted list of pairs (I didn not test this!):

```
% case of Index hit:

go_through([Index-Value|Rest],Index,InList,OutList) :-
   InList  = [I|Rest],
   OutList = [Value|More],
   succ(Index,NextIndex),
   go_through(Rest,NextIndex,Rest,More).

% case of Index miss:

go_through([NotYetIndex-Value|Rest],Index,InList,OutList) :-   
   NotYetIndex > Index,  % that should be the case
   InList  = [I|Rest],
   OutList = [I|More],
   succ(Index,NextIndex),
   go_through(Rest,NextIndex,Rest,More).

go_through([],_,L,L). % DONE
```

Alternatively, you can write a `replace0` that replaces-by-index in a list, and go through the `L` list.

## Addendum: Working code using go_through

Actually contains a few subtlties

```
another_vectorial_replace1(ListIn,ReplacePairs,ListOut) :-
   maplist([_,_]>>true,ListIn,ListOut),               % Bonus code: This "makes sure" (i.e. fails if not) 
                                                      % that ListIn and ListOut are the same length
   maplist([(A,B),A-B]>>true,ReplacePairs,RealPairs), % Transform all (1,b) into [1,b]
   maplist([K-_]>>integer(K),RealPairs),              % Make sure the RealPairs all have integers on first place   
   keysort(RealPairs,RealPairsSorted),                % Sorting by key, which are integers; dups are not removed!
   debug(topic,"ListIn: ~q",[ListIn]),
   debug(topic,"RealPairsSorted: ~q",[RealPairsSorted]),
   go_through(RealPairsSorted,1,ListIn,ListOut),
   debug(topic,"ListOut: ~q",[ListOut]).

% Case of Index hit, CurIndex is found in the first "Replacement Pair"

go_through([CurIndex-Value|RestPairs],CurIndex,ListIn,ListOut) :-
   !, % Commit to choice
   ListIn  = [_|Rest],
   ListOut = [Value|More],
   succ(CurIndex,NextIndex),
   go_through(RestPairs,NextIndex,Rest,More).

% Case of Index miss:

go_through([NotYetIndex-V|RestPairs],CurIndex,ListIn,ListOut) :-
   NotYetIndex > CurIndex,  % that should be the case because of sorting; fail if not
   !, % Commit to choice
   ListIn  = [X|Rest],
   ListOut = [X|More],
   succ(CurIndex,NextIndex),
   go_through([NotYetIndex-V|RestPairs],NextIndex,Rest,More).

% Case of DONE with list traversal
% Only succeed if there are not more pairs left (i.e. no out-of-bound replacements)

go_through([],_CurIndex,L,L).

% ===
% Tests
% ===

:- begin_tests(another_vectorial_replace1).

test(empty)  :- another_vectorial_replace1([],[],LO),
                LO=[].

test(nop_op) :- another_vectorial_replace1([a,b,c,d],[],LO),
                LO=[a,b,c,d].

test(one)    :- another_vectorial_replace1([a],[(1,xxx)],LO),        
                LO=[xxx].

test(two)    :- another_vectorial_replace1([a,b,c,d],[(4,y),(2,x)],LO),
                LO=[a,x,c,y].

test(full)   :- another_vectorial_replace1([a,b,c,d],[(1,e),(2,f),(3,g),(4,h)],LO),
                LO=[e,f,g,h].

test(duplicate_replacement,[fail]) :- another_vectorial_replace1([a],[(1,x),(1,y)],_). 
test(out_of_bounds_high,[fail])     :- another_vectorial_replace1([a],[(2,y)],_).
test(out_of_bounds_low,[fail])    :- another_vectorial_replace1([a],[(0,y)],_).

:- end_tests(another_vectorial_replace1).

rt :- debug(topic),run_tests(another_vectorial_replace1).
```

## Addendum 2

Replacement using `maplist/N`, `foldl/N` and `library(assoc)`

Recursive calls disappear behind the curtain!

https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/blob/master/code/vector_replace0.pl

Comment: Thank for the suggestion, the list is already sorted so step 1 wont be necessary. Since english is not my native language, I would just like to make sure of something: in the pair 1-b, 1 is the key and b is the value right? And how would I use such key as the index of list? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @FranciscoCunha Yes Key is First Position, Value Second. I will add an example based on `library(assoc)` because I always wanted to program "vectorial replace-in-list" just had a brainwave that `library(assoc)` solves this problem directly (though maybe with statistically significant computational overhead?)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on the `library(pairs)` part? (I tried to implement both the `pairs` and the `assoc` libraries and the first seems to better fit what I want to do.) I have separated the list of pairs into two lists: A with the values and B with the keys. How do I run through both lists at the same time while changing the original list at the corresponding index?

Comment: @FranciscoCunha I have added some code for "going through the input list". You do not need to separate - let Prolog do the disassembly in `[Index-Value|Rest]`. The important part is that list must be sorted by Key ascending.

Comment: A few questions about the go_through() predicate: 1- When I first call it, what should go in the Index?, 2- When I tried to run that, I got 5 different "Singleton Variables" warnings, 3- Though I understand the function minimally, I sdon't get the need for an  `InList` and `OutList` since I just want to change one list, not create a new one. Could you test the code a bit please?

Comment: @FranciscoCunha Regarding the `InList` and `OutList`, as one cannot (should not) change existing data structures "in place", one only constructs new datstructures from existing ones. So, given `InList`, we construct/specify a new list, `OutList` forged from various parts, including parts from `InList`.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer that's *functional* programming approach.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but I'm gonna have to take Isabelle's answer since it's really straightforward. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: @WillNess Well, yes. But you still have the same problem here, as you want to replace in a list.

Comment: we increase our knowledge about a list's element, not replace it. the element stays the same, it's just getting defined more and more. It's like writing `A=[1|B], B=[2|C], C=[3|D], ...`.

Comment: @WillNess You are right of course. But there is a dual view somehow - functional when you stay at the predicate's surface definition (very strongly so when looking athings like [put_assoc/4](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=put_assoc/4), constraint-increasing when you think about the recursive descent. I need to write this down.

Answer (score 1):

*(the following assumes that the indices in the pairs list will be sorted, in increasing order, as the example in the question indicates.)*

What you said can be written as one conjunction

```erlang
  E=[A,B,C,D], L=[(1,a),(3,c)], solve(E,L), E=[a,B,c,D].
```

which you intend to be holding under the proper definition of `solve/2` that you seek to find. But isn't it like saying

```erlang
  E=[A|E2],    L=[(1,a)|L2], 
       E2=[B,C,D],      L2=[(3,c)],
                               solve(E2,L2),     E2=[B,c,D], 
                                            E=[a|E2].
```

? Although, something doesn't quite fit right, here. `c` in `E2` appears in  *second* position, not `3`rd as indicated by its entry in `L2`.

But naturally, `L2` must be indexed from *2*, since it is a tail of `L` which is indexed from *1*. So we must make *this* explicit:

```erlang
  E=[A,B,C,D], L=[(1,a),(3,c)], solve(E,L), E=[a,B,c,D]
==
  E=[A,B,C,D], L=[(1,a),(3,c)], solve(E,1,L), E=[a,B,c,D]          % starting index 1
==
  E=[A|E2],    L=[(1,a)|L2], 
       E2=[B,C,D],      L2=[(3,c)],
                               solve(E2,2,L2), E2=[B,c,D], E=[a|E2]
```

must, and now *can*, hold. But where did `a` get from, in `E`? What we actually mean here is

```erlang
  E=[A|E2],    L=[(1,a)|L2],
               p( (1,a),                1,                    a),   % index match
       E2=[B,C,D],      L2=[(3,c)],
                               solve(E2,2,L2), E2=[B,c,D],          % starting index 2
                                                           E=[a|E2]
```

with `p/3` defined as

```erlang
p( (I,A), I, A).
```

And so it must also hold that

```erlang
       E2=[B|E3],       L2=[(3,c)],
                    \+ p(   (3,c),      2,         c),              % index mismatch
             E3=[C,D],     L3=L2,
                               solve(E3,3,L3), E3=[c,D], E2=[B|E3]
```

`L2` is *not* traversed along at this step (`L3=L2`), since `p( (3,c), 2, c)` does *not* hold.

Do you see how the *recursive* definition of `solve/3` reveals itself here? Could you finish it up?